# React Navigation understanding navigator nestings

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, navigation, react-navigation

I've been using react-navigation for almost half a year, but I still don't understand the nesting part of it. How the navigation prop is inherited, how to communicate, etc..

I created a demo on snack, from the redux example app.

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xyzor/reactnavigationredux)

I'd like to understand these:

1. What happens with the navigation prop if I navigate to a child navigator?
2. How to navigate from a child navigators screen to the parents screen or the parents other child's screen
3. How to remove a child navigator from the state?

The simplest example:
On a login event I reset the navigator with the Main StackNavigator.
The problem with this is, that I have to rebuild manually the whole Main state.
It would be much easier If I could just remove somehow the Auth StackNavigator and keep the Main Stack.

4. Is it possible to trigger redux event with the child navigators navigate actions?

I wrapped the Main navigation (StackNavigator) component with a redux component as the doc says. It works fine until I navigate into a child component. The navigation props niavigate method stops dispatching redux actions.

5. This, I couldn't recreate in the demo

I have a Component and a DrawerNavigator inside a StackNavigator.
If i navigate into the DrawerNavigator (there is only 1 screen there) from the Component, I can't go back to that Component with this:

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

The odd part is that its only impossible inside the screen's component. From the screen's header component its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It can always access in `props.navigation`.
2. `reset` action is needed in order to navigate to parent/child navigator.
   Also, due to [#1127](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1127) `key: null` is required
3. `navigation.replace` is another option for login navigate to main screen if the screens are in same navigator, use `reset` if animated transition is required. Or see other methods in [#295](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/295)
4. `navigate` can only navigate to screen in same navigator, refer to answer 3 for other methods.
5. maybe the component is missing `navigation` props

[Working Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@indream/reactnavigationredux)

Comment: 1. I know that It can access a navigation object from the props.
I'd like to know, in case of going into a child navigator, this props.navigation object gets replaced by the child navigator's own navigation object or happens something else?

2. If I'm in the child navigator, then to navigate (or reset) to a sibling navigator, I must have the parents navigation object (e.g in screenProps), right?

5. It has a navigation props, but that only contains the DrawerNavigator's screens.

I checked your demo, and when it resets to MainDrawer, the Profile route is missing from the state.

Comment: @Xyzor 1. It's the same object. 2. Reset means rebuild the state, you can use reset with multiple navigate action and change the `index` params. 5. If you need Profile located in the drawer, you need to put in inside `MainDrawerNavigator`.

Comment: Thanks your help. I was able to fix the navigation problem.

My problem was that I couldn't navigate between nested navigators with the navigate method.
So I passed down the root navigation param in screenProps, and dispatched the reset action with this root navigation. Which didn't get passed down to the grand-childrens. Thats why it worked only in the root navigation's childs.

Although 1 strange thing happens. If a navigate deeper and deeper, more and more "Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION" action gets dispatched after a navigation. Is this normal?

Comment: I don't think it's not normal, could you update the snack to your current state?